# Error al momento de crear el Procedimiento almacenado en Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server-2008-r2

Hola tengo el siguiente error para crear mi SP en mysql

```
Create PROCEDURE SP_VoucheProducto(in tk varchar(150)) AS
select cotizacion.id_cotizacion,cotizacion.monto,h_cotizacion.cantidad,cotizacion.Descripcion,cotizacion.tipo_pago,cotizacion.numero_cuotas,cotizacion.fecha_pago,productos.nombre_productos,productos.tiempo_productos,productos.garantia_productos,cliente.nombre_cliente,cliente.correo_cliente,cliente.fono_cliente,cliente.razon_social,cliente.rut_cliente
from h_cotizacion
inner join productos on h_cotizacion.id_producto = productos.id_productos
inner join cotizacion on h_cotizacion.id_cotizacion = cotizacion.id_cotizacion
inner join cliente on h_cotizacion.id_cliente = cliente.id_cliente
where cotizacion.token_ws = tk
```

ERROR: Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AS select cotizacion.id_cotizacion,cotizacion.monto,h_cotizacion.cantidad,cotiza' at line 1

Comment: Estás implementando mal la sintaxis. La cual es más o menos así: `DELIMITER //
 CREATE PROCEDURE TuProcedure()
   BEGIN
   SELECT ... tu select completo;
   END //
 DELIMITER ;` todo lo que es `DELIMITER, BEGIN, END` es fundamental en SP. [Revisa el Manual de Referencia](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-procedure.html) y si no lo entiendes del todo, [revisa este tutorial](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/getting-started-with-mysql-stored-procedures.aspx). Saludos.

Comment: Gracias me sirvió :D

Answer (score 0):

No has especificado el inicio y el fin de tu procedimiento debe estar de esta manera

```
Create PROCEDURE SP_VoucheProducto(tk varchar(150)) AS
begin
select cotizacion.id_cotizacion,cotizacion.monto,h_cotizacion.cantidad,cotizacion.Descripcion,cotizacion.tipo_pago,cotizacion.numero_cuotas,cotizacion.fecha_pago,productos.nombre_productos,productos.tiempo_productos,productos.garantia_productos,cliente.nombre_cliente,cliente.correo_cliente,cliente.fono_cliente,cliente.razon_social,cliente.rut_cliente
from h_cotizacion
inner join productos on h_cotizacion.id_producto = productos.id_productos
inner join cotizacion on h_cotizacion.id_cotizacion = cotizacion.id_cotizacion
inner join cliente on h_cotizacion.id_cliente = cliente.id_cliente
where cotizacion.token_ws = tk
end
```